# Doctrine statement is not returning data correctly when raw query is used

Tags: sql, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

Using symfony4 I have a raw query in one of my repositories which receives two dates as paramenters to result in something as follow:

```
SELECT ss.company_name, count(ss.id) AS total, 
        count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.container_dimention = '20') AS total_20,
        count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.container_dimention = '40') AS total_40, count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.container_type = 'RH') AS total_rh, count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.container_type != 'RH') AS total_dry, count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.container_type = 'RH' AND ss.days_in_tcm > 7) AS total_rh_plus_seven, count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.days_in_tcm > 3) AS total_plus_three, count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.days_in_tcm > 3 AND ss.container_type = 'RH') AS total_plus_three_rh, count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.days_in_tcm > 15) AS total_plus_fifteen, count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.is_enabled) AS total_enabled, count(ss.id) filter (WHERE NOT ss.is_locked) AS total_locked FROM shipment ss WHERE ss.extraction_at IS NULL AND ss.arrived_at BETWEEN '2019-11-30' AND '2019-12-02' GROUP BY ss.company_name
```

This query is taken from the profiler...

After building the query I do as follow

```
    $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($dql);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The problem is when I execute the generated query on PostgreSQL console I get one result but the fetch method is returning an empty array.

Any tip about why is happening this, there is no error in the profiler and the query is OK as is returning results on server console.

Thanks in advance!

> Update

```
$dql = "SELECT ss.company_name, count(ss.id) AS total, 
        count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.container_dimention = '" . 20 . "') AS total_20,
        count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.container_dimention = '" . 40 . "') AS total_40";

    $dql .= ", count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.container_type = 'RH') AS total_rh";
    $dql .= ", count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.container_type != 'RH') AS total_dry";

    $dql .= ", count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.container_type = 'RH' AND ss.days_in_tcm > 7) AS total_rh_plus_seven";
    $dql .= ", count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.days_in_tcm > 3) AS total_plus_three";
    $dql .= ", count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.days_in_tcm > 3 AND ss.container_type = 'RH') AS total_plus_three_rh";
    $dql .= ", count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.days_in_tcm > 15) AS total_plus_fifteen";
    $dql .= ", count(ss.id) filter (WHERE ss.is_enabled) AS total_enabled";
    $dql .= ", count(ss.id) filter (WHERE NOT ss.is_locked) AS total_locked";

    $dql .= ' FROM shipment ss WHERE ss.extraction_at IS NULL';

    foreach ($filters as $property => $options) {
      if ($property == 'arrivedAt') {
        if (array_key_exists('after', $options) && array_key_exists('before', $options)) {
          $dql .= " AND ss.arrived_at BETWEEN '" . $options['after'] . "' AND '" . $options['before'] . "'";
        } elseif (array_key_exists('after', $options)) {
          $dql .= " AND ss.arrived_at > '" . $options['after'] . "'";
        } elseif (array_key_exists('before', $options)) {
          $dql .= " AND ss.arrived_at < '" . $options['before'] . "'";
        }
      }
    }

    $dql .= ' GROUP BY ss.company_name';
```

Comment: Can you add the `$dql` used here `$stmt = $conn->prepare($dql);` to the OP?

Comment: It reads dql but is sql. updated already

Comment: one possibly very unfortunate possibility would be: when you run the query on console, you run it against a different database? try running the query via `bin/console doctrine:query:sql "yourquery"`. the *wrong* connection credentials (to a different database) is sometimes overlooked.